# k[$c].maps.Load is not a function

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I want to load a map with pins stored in json file in angular app.
but i'm facing with this error!
`k[$c].maps.Load is not a function`

```
appControllers.controller('mapController', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("data/markers.json").success(function(data) {
        $scope.offices = data;
        $scope.insertGoogleScript();
    });

    $scope.insertGoogleScript = function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=loaded";
        document.getElementById('mainMap').appendChild(script);
    }

    $scope.loadMap = function() {
        angular.forEach($scope.offices, function(office) {
            console.log('#');
        });
    }

});

function loaded() {
    var appElement = document.querySelector('[ng-controller="mapController"]');
    var $scope = angular.element(appElement).scope();
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.loadMap();
    });
}
```

Comment: Could it be that you've included the maps-API multiple times(take a look at the console, there should be a related message when it does)?

Comment: you are right! controllers inheritance make it loaded twice! tnx